# How did Near know that Kira must be in the room?

Tags: death-note

In the Death Note anime episode 30, Near has a call with L2, aka Light and the task force. When he gets the information that a Shimigami is in the room with them, he concludes that Kira must be in the room. Why is it so? Or, if it's logical, why nobody else, especially Light thought about it?

Edit: I just remembered in the morning that he concludes so because the Shimigami is lying. How did Light not think about that, what it will mean to the others, not just Near.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scene of that same episode Near says that the new L is Kira (based on how convenient was Kira's exchange with the Japanese task force), he's not sure but he's assuming that, further on in the episode Near learns about the existence of the Shinigami and the fake rule (the rule that proves Light's innocence), and then during the call he's told that there is a Shinigami in the room. At this point Near is already confident enough to bet his life to test if the rule is indeed fake, with his request to test the rule denied, Near spreads doubt among the task force, which leads Kira to wanting to kill Near as soon as possible.